# How to get url of uploaded media in supabase storage in flutter?

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

In flutter for uploading image according to doc is

```
final avatarFile = File('path/to/file');
final response = await supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .upload('public/avatar1.png', avatarFile, fileOptions: FileOptions(
    cacheControl: '3600',
    upsert: false
  ));
```

So, how we can get the downloadUrl of this uploaded media ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `getPublicUrl` method:

```
final res = supabase
  .storage
  .from('avatars')
  .getPublicUrl('public/avatar1.png');

final publicURL = res.data;
```

See https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/storage-from-getpublicurl

Answer (score 0):

To receive downloadUrls of your uploaded media, you need to create a subscription to the media table.

The following snippet will create a subscription to the media table and log each media item as it is created:

```dart
mediaSubscription = supabase
    .from('media')
    .subscribe((event) {
      print(event.doc.data);
  });
```

Comment: i cant find your solution in documents